# Always remember this one thing

Tags: cipher

After a particularly rough day, Ann went to her abuela for advice. Being rather cryptic, her grandmother provided her this picture and said, "The blocks are always happy, because they remember this one thing."

[image]

If you don't believe me, check out the simple markup that makes up the table!

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#165">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#16c">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#273">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#462">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#472">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#469">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#365">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#373">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#26f">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#46c">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#46c">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#461">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#374">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#361">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#26c">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#46e">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#464">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background:#46f">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What is it the blocks keep in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the hex values, we see:

> The last two digits can be read as ASCII. This gives: `elsbri / esolla / talndo`.
>
>  The first digits, in their proper positions, form "blocks":
>   `112444`
>   `332444`
>   `332444`

So, the thing to remember is

> found by reading the ASCII characters in the numbered blocks, in order. This gives **`EL SOL ESTA BRILLANDO`**, Spanish for "the sun is shining"!

Comment: I have to figure out how to make these harder - well done. I was hoping to make the html table in SE so it at least took a right click -> inspect. No luck though.